# How can I code "If statement with Case" in a line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code now.

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
```

However, there are also "info", and "block" beside these two such as "success", and error.

Unfortunately, when `name == :notice', it has to be "success".
But everything else just can be as it is just like

```
when `name == :error`, it has to be "error"  
when `name == :info`, it has to be "info"  
when `name == :block`, it has to be "block"
```

How can I code them in a line supposing these 4 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one exception, then how about:

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? 'success' : name.to_s %>">
```

Comment: I would rather go for a helper here.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Using helper for many times will make app slower, won't it?

Comment: I don't think it will make anything slower, it's such a small piece of code. But here it you have just two cases helper may be an overkill.